# Throw Exception when a wrong type is keyed in

Tags: c++, exception

I have to write a C++ program in which a function is to read two `double` type numbers from keyboard and add a `try` block to throw an exception when a wrong type is keyed in. I have used `cin.fail()` function but it did not work.

Here's what I have tried so far, but it will not throw exception if I'm entering double value.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<conio.h>
using namespace std;


int main() 
{

    double j;
    try{
        cin>>j;
        if (cin.fail())
            throw (j);
        else
            cout << "Double Value " << j << endl;  
    }
    catch(double a)
    {
        cout<<"Incompatible Datatype for value"<<a;
    }

}
```

Comment: Side note:  Someone typing in the wrong data is *not* an exceptional condition requiring throwing exceptions.  In C++, exceptions should be reserved for those **exceptional** cases, not if someone has fat fingers and hits the wrong key on the keyboard.

Comment: This is the Complete definition of program.                                 
 Write a program with the following
• A function to read two double type numbers from keyboard
• A function to calculate the division of these two numbers
• A try block to throw an exception when a wrong type is keyed in
• A try block to detect and throw an exception if the condition “divide-by-zero” occurs
• Appropriate catch block to handle the exceptions thrown

Comment: *but it did not work.* -- This is not a sufficient description.  Please describe the results you're seeing, and what results you expect.  Also your assignment explicitly states to enter two doubles, so why are you declaring your types as `int`?

Comment: @Bhagyasripatel According to your description, you have to read `double` values. In your code sample, you use `int i;` and `cin >> i;`. If I understood it right it should be `double i;`.

Comment: @ PaulMcKenzie and @Scheff ...I have Edited my Question. The output that i m Excpecting is that if i m entering integer value, the program will throw Exception. Currently the program is throwing Exception if i m entering character values...

Comment: @Bhagyasripatel An integer value entered *is* a valid double.  There is nothing wrong in entering `123` if the type is a double.

Answer (score 0):

What about catching a string and handling exceptions?
Below is the the general idea:

```
string d;

    try{
        cin >> d;
        if ( d.find_first_not_of("0123456789-+.") != string::npos)
        {
            throw std::runtime_error("not an int");
        }
        else if ( ( strtod( d.c_str(),nullptr ) > INT_MAX ) || ( strtod( d.c_str(),nullptr ) < INT_MIN ) )
        {
            throw std::runtime_error(" int overflow");
        }

    }
    catch(const std::exception&d)
    {
        cout << d.what() << endl;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
double a, b;
void accept()
{

    cout << "Enter any two Numbers\n";

    try
    {
        cin >> a;
        if (cin.fail())
            throw(a);
        cin >> b;
        if (cin.fail())
            throw(b);
    }
    catch (...)
    {
        cout << "Incompatible Datatype for value\n";
        exit(0);
    }
}

int main()

{

    accept();


    return 0;
}
```

I think this will work.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Two approaches to this 5 year old question: try/catch and reading the [failbit](https://cplusplus.com/reference/ios/ios/fail/).

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <limits>

int main()
{
    /* Using try/catch */

    std::string a;
    double A;
    
    std::cout << "Digit A: "; std::getline(std::cin, a);
    
    try // Try to execute code below without problem 
    {
        A = stod(a); // stod, string-to-double
        std::cout << A << std::endl;
    }
    catch (std::invalid_argument&) // Catch when a specific problem occurs
    {
        std::cout << "Invalid first digit" << std::endl;
    }


    /* Another way; std::cin >> double, catch if fail when input isn't double */

    double B;

    std::cout << "Digit B: "; std::cin >> B;

    if (std::cin.fail()) // If failbit is set, clear the failbit flag and clear input buffer until it hits '\n'*
    {
        // https://gist.github.com/leimao/418395bf920eb70b2b11fe89d7c1f738
        std::cin.clear();
        std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
        
        std::cout << "Invalid second digit" << std::endl;
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << B << std::endl;
    }


    return 0;
}
```

To note, when at least the first inputted character is of the correct type and the rest isn't (particularly for decimal types), the variable value assignment still goes through, and discards the rest of the input starting from the first different type character. Means that in this case, `Digit A: 123F5` turns into `123`.